# How to change color pixels to white pixels

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision

I got a color image as input and I want to check the color information(like [0, 0, 0] - [255, 255, 255]) on the variance. So if the variance is over a certain point I want to change it to white.

So something like that:

```
for y in range(img.shape[0]):
    for x in range(img.shape[1]):
        if numpy.var(img[y][x]) > 1000:
            img[y][x] = [255, 255, 255]
```

But I need good performance. So I tried it with the numpy.where() function, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: not sure I understand, is it like a gray scale image you are looking for???

Comment: @Inder No. I don't want to change color pixels to a gray scale. I want to change color pixels like red [255, 0, 0] or green [0, 255,0] to white [255, 255, 255]. So I'm using variance on the color information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy`'s indexing for this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = (np.random.rand(100,100,3)*255).astype(int)

img2 = np.copy(img)
img2[np.var(img, 2)>1000] = np.array([255, 255, 255])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[1].imshow(img2)
```

The second parameter of `np.var` is the axis you want to calculate the variance on; in this case the colors.

Result:

[image]